# Predicate Logic "John drinks any type of drink"

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

For the following English statement,what would be the correct predicate logic translation:

**John drinks any type of drink**.

1.$\forall x {(Drinks(John,x))}$

2.$\forall x(Drink(x) \to Drinks(John,x)\\$

I would read the statement back into English as:

1. John drinks all everything.
2. John drinks everything that is a drink.

Comment: Yes, both readings are correct. So for your initial statement, the second one would be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the first one is that John is part of the domain, and hence it implies that John drinks himself!

So, I would definitely go with the second one.

Comment: Bram28, thanks for writing up this answer (have deleted mine for being at best superfluous)!

Comment: @ryang I appreciate it! You are graceful as always .. I wish there would be more of you on this site :)

Comment: Gosh, thanks for your very kind words!